# intro.js disableInteraction not working as expected

Tags: jquery, intro.js

*FYI - This is question is probably way easier to understand having had experience using this plugin.*

I am using [intro.js](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js) to build an interactive tour on my webpage and for the most part it has been working well. In [options](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/#attributes), listed in the API, there is disableInteraction. I take this option to mean that the user is (still) able to interact with the element highlighted in each 'step'. i.e. if the step highlights a button and the text for the step reads like "now click the button to open the file", then that button would still be clickable.

I have been passing said option like so:

```
introJs().setOption("disableInteraction", "false").start();
```

but no luck; buttons are not clickable when they are highlighted as part of an IntroJs 'step'. I've tried passing other options this way and they've worked fine. Anyone had any experienced with this?

Answer (score 3):

I started using this plugin today and I had the same issue.

I found [this fix](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/pull/368) and it works well for me.

Comment: Yes, this fixes the problem. Strangely enough they don't merge the fix.